# Jenkins GIT Fetching Error

Tags: git, visual-studio, jenkins, bitbucket

I just started getting this error after installing the new update to Visual Studio.  For some reason, none of my builds will now fetch from Jenkins.  Been at this for several hours now and can't seem to figure it out.

I fetch from BitBucket.

Please Help.

Started by timer
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CA
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://bitbucket.org/XXXXX/CA.git

> git init C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\CA\CA # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://bitbucket.org/XXXX/CA.git
>   git --version # timeout=10
>   using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket
>   git fetch --tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/XXXX/CA.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
>   ERROR: Failed to join a process
>   org.jvnet.winp.WinpException: Process with pid=26808 is not a 32bit process (or it is not running). Cannot query it from a 32bit library error=268435458 at envvar-cmdline.cpp:183
>       at org.jvnet.winp.Native.getCmdLine(Native Method)
>       at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.parseCmdLine(WinProcess.java:132)
>       at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.getCommandLine(WinProcess.java:107)
>       at hudson.util.ProcessTree$WindowsOSProcess.getArguments(ProcessTree.java:451)
>       at hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildKillingVeto.vetoProcessKilling(MsBuildKillingVeto.java:56)
>       at hudson.util.ProcessTree$OSProcess.getVeto(ProcessTree.java:243)
>       at hudson.util.ProcessTree$WindowsOSProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:429)
>       at hudson.util.ProcessTree.killAll(ProcessTree.java:146)
>       at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.destroy(Proc.java:384)
>       at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.kill(Proc.java:376)
>       at hudson.Proc$1.run(Proc.java:163)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/XXXX/CA.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: 
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1924)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1643)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:352)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:559)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1075)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1115)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.multiplescms.MultiSCM.checkout(MultiSCM.java:143)
>       at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1212)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:566)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:491)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1729)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
>   ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Please try to setting Source Code Management → Branches to build → */develop

Comment: Sometime Jenkins with Bitbucket Plugin can't pull special branch with your customize name. Just can pull `develop` or `master`...

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn these are only pulling from develop or master.  They don't fetch from any other branch names.

Comment: @SpoiledTechie.com does your BitBucket password contains any special character? It looks like an authentication failure to me.

Comment: Are you using Git or JGit in Git plugin? Try to change this.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the msbuild version to one for VS2017. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error after upgrading Visual Studio on the same machine Jenkins runs on, which required a reboot. I suspect the reboot was the cause over the upgrade.

Re-entering the btibucket URL and saving the project fixed this for me. I am not entirely sure why, my assumption is something Jenkins was caching about git was wiped during the reboot.